# Augmented reality android (andAR) movie texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality, andar

I am developing an augmented reality app on android using andAR. I want to play a movie texture instead of 3d model when a marker is detected. Can anyone tell me how to do it. I am new to android and no knowledge of opengl . I dont want to use qualcomm or metaio sdk because , metaio has a watermark with free license and also qualcomm sdk. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a watermark and are okay with it being in an AR browser rather than your own app, you should use [Junaio](http://www.junaio.com).

You can use their API to build it, or use the [Creator](http://www.metaio.com/products/creator), which will let you drag and drop the video onto a marker without any coding.

If you launch the AR experience into Junaio, there shouldn't be a watermark. You'd just be opening up a channel in their browser. You can then eventually launch it into your own app but, like the sdk, you'll need to pay to get rid of the watermark.